# UI5 performance parameters: data-sap-ui-preload vs. data-sap-ui-async

Tags: performance, asynchronous, sapui5

Different SAPUI5 performance guidelines mention two key parameters, which seem to have similar nature, but slightly different explanation:

1. [**`data-sap-ui-preload="async"`**](https://help.sap.com/viewer/b4b7cba328bc480d9b373c7da9335537/2.13/en-US/408b40efed3c416681e1bd8cdd8910d4.html)

> *The most important setting here is `data-sap-ui-preload="async"`. This enables the runtime to load the modules for all declared libraries asynchronously in the background. This reduces the amount of requests sent by the client that could block each other.*

2. [**`data-sap-ui-async="true"`**](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/408b40efed3c416681e1bd8cdd8910d4)

> *The most important setting is `data-sap-ui-async="true"`. This enables the runtime to load all the modules and preload files for all declared libraries asynchronously, if an asynchronous API is used. Setting `async=true` leverages the browser's capabilities to execute multiple requests in parallel, without blocking the UI thread.*

Could you please clarify what exactly the difference, when should I use one over another?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first linked documentation is based on the **outdated UI5 version `1.38.x`**. At that time, the config `sap-ui-preload="async"` was indeed "the most important setting" since there was no `sap-ui-async` available back then. With version `1.58.2`, the `async="true"` was introduced which should be used instead of `preload="true"` as stated in the topic *[Configuration Options and URL Parameters](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/91f2d03b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070)*:

> #### `preload` (Deprecated)
>
> This configuration parameter defines the loading behaviour of the so-called *preload files*. […] The values are used as follows:
>
> - […]
> - When set to `async`, the preload files are loaded asynchronously. However, **we recommend to use the `async=true` configuration parameter in the bootstrap instead**, because it switches more module/related APIs to async **including** the loading behaviour of the preload files.

> #### `async`
>
> This configuration setting enables the module loader to **load both, modules and library-preload files asynchronously**.

---

## TL;DR

```js
data-sap-ui-async="true" // since 1.58 --> can replace preload="async"*
```

```js
data-sap-ui-preload="async" // deprecated
```

* Prerequisite: [*Is Your Application Ready for Asynchronous Loading?*](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/493a15aa978d4fe9a67ea9407166eb01.html)

Answer (score 3):

I wanna add some more information to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54804167/5846045) of Boghyon. It's not a replacement in regards to `data-sap-ui-async` and `data-sap-ui-preload`. `data-sap-ui-async` is an additional offering which enables simply more asynchronous features of UI5. See also the [performance section](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/408b40efed3c416681e1bd8cdd8910d4).

> [image: Note from the OpenUI5 documentation section "Enable Asynchronous Loading in the Bootstrap"]

Comment: From _«The bootstrap attribute `data-sap-ui-async="true"` affects both modules and preload files. If it is not possible to load the modules asynchronously (e.g. for compatibility reasons), use `data-sap-ui-preload="async"` to configure at least the preloads for asynchronous loading.»_ I can infer that `data-sap-ui-async` overlaps the `data-sap-ui-preload` property, in other words, `data-sap-ui-async` does everything what `data-sap-ui-preload` does, plus some extra things for the benefit of asynchronization. Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: Yes, @Mike B. You named it. `data-sap-ui-async` does everything what `data-sap-ui-preload` does, plus some extra things for the benefit of asynchronization.